# Do I need to delete a post myself for the peer pressure badge?

Tags: support, peer-pressure-badge

I asked a question, which was poorly received. At the time of writing I wasn't thinking straight so I ended up asking a primarily opinion based question. Usually when this happens I just let the question sit there with its downvotes. That's when I noticed the peer pressure badge. I tried deleting the question, but it wouldn't let me since it had an upvoted answer. So now if I'd flag it for moderation asking for it to be deleted, will it earn me the peer pressure badge? Because I do feel pressured to get this post deleted!

Comment: @ProgramFOX I see. For future readers. The link says *Posts that you own but are not self deleted do not count.* So I guess I can't earn the badge on this question :( Too bad.